# Deal with collision between Player and Wall

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I'm developing a 2D game with javascript. I have to detect if a player is in a certain position (a door or a wall) in order to make some actions. The collisions work well on my desktop but if I change resolution all positions i checked before doesn't work anymore. Is there any way to improve a good *collision detection system* that works also if i change the desktop's resolution ?

What i'm doing right now is pretty like this :

Here is the html structure:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="main">
    <img id="palyer" src="../img/sprites/pleyer.png">
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
#container{
margin: auto;
width: 60%;
height: 80%;}

#main{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; }

    #player{
        position: relative;
        top: 100px;
        left: 400px;}
```

And the js:

```
var position = $("#player").position();
if((position.left<=55)&&(position.top>=183)&&(position.top<=215)){
changeRoom();}
```

Comment: I assume `55`, `183` and `215` are the pixels at which you want to change room. Don't you have access to the total size of the frame, so you can set these values in relation to it?

Comment: Yes, they are pixel values, I placed the game room in a div and all the game's elements inside this div. So i assume i have to acces the position of the elements relative to the div but all the methods i tried so far are "resolution-dipendent".

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to suggest without seeing the rest of the code, but one way around the problem is to have two variables to hold values for X and Y ratios. Then you multiply all your coordinates by these ratios every time you use it. The last piece needed is to update those ratios every time your game is resized, with something like this

```
window.onresize = function onResize(event) {

   var canvas = document.getElementById('myGameScreen'); // reference to your html element 
   var newHeight = canvas.clientHeight;
   var newWidth = canvas.clientWidth;

   var ratioY = newHeight / oldHeight;
   var ratioX = newWidth / oldWidth;
   ...
   ...
   ...
   // save new dimensions for the next resize event
   oldHeight = newHeight;
   oldWidth = newWidth;
 }
```